# VBA to Sort in Descending order - based on Average

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, average

Hope you'll can help..!

I have this list like this..

```
Item    Value
Prod_1  0.22 
Prod_2  0.30 
Prod_3  0.23 
Prod_4  0.22 
Prod_5  0.28 
Prod_6  0.23 
Prod_7  0.22 
Prod_8  0.28 
Prod_9  0.24
```

I would want to group them in 3's so that average of those three items would need to be sorted in descending order..

Here the challenge is to know which combination needs to be used - I guess sorting them later..

Kindly see below..!

This is what I want to get..

```
Name    Value   Average  

Prod_1  0.22    0.2500000
Prod_2  0.30        
Prod_6  0.23        

Prod_9  0.24    0.2466667
Prod_5  0.28        
Prod_7  0.22        

Prod_4  0.22    0.2433333
Prod_8  0.28        
Prod_3  0.23
```

Currently I have 9 items.. but this would be n number and will always needed to be in the group of 3..

I tried other methods.. but was not successful..

Comment: please add the vba code and tellus what you tried; it is not clear how the triplets should be grouped

Comment: A list? You mean a range on your sheet, or a variant array variable, or ...? Please provide code.

Comment: Honestly I am a beginner - Not sure how to start the logic.. - So I was looking at Permutation and combination VBA  - And yes its a Range for a specific sheet

Comment: How do you decide which groups of three to put together?  Will your total number always be divisible by three?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the product names in column A, row 2 to 10, ie, Prod_1, etc, and put their corresponding values in column "B" rows 2 through 10, then this subroutine will do what your example asks for explicitly.  It might help you get an idea as to how VBA scripting works so you can modify it later to meet your new needs as they arise.

Within the code you will see two arrays being created, originalArray, which is a multi dimensional array.  It has 9 items which hold two pieces of data - name and value.  It is filled with a loop going from row 2 to row 10, gathering each row of data into a new row in the array.

Next we have an array of your separated elements, or rather how you want the groups separated into 3.  That is also a multidimensional array but it is initialized and defined in one step.

The n the "For" loop is added to place the groups by three in columns "E" and "F" and to put their average into Column "G".  Then it skips a line and does the next group of 3, then skips a line and does the last group of 3.

Study the code carefully, or even step through it with F8 key, and it will help you understand how the code runs - top to bottom -

```
Sub getAvgs()
Dim origArray(1 To 9, 1 To 2)
Dim varData, rowCounter As Long, averager As Double

    For i = 1 To 9
        origArray(i, 1) = Sheet1.Range("A" & i + 1).Value
        origArray(i, 2) = Sheet1.Range("B" & i + 1).Value
    Next i

    varData = [{1, 2, 6; 9, 5, 7; 4, 8, 3}]


    rowCounter = 3
    Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00000"
    Columns("E:G").ColumnWidth = 12
    Sheet1.Range("E1").Value = "Name"
    Sheet1.Range("F1").Value = "Value"
    Sheet1.Range("G1").Value = "Average"


    For i = 1 To 3
        For f = 1 To 3
            Sheet1.Range("E" & rowCounter).Value = origArray(varData(f, i), 1)
            Sheet1.Range("F" & rowCounter).Value = origArray(varData(f, i), 2)
            averager = averager + origArray(varData(1, f), 2)
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
        Next f
        Sheet1.Range("G" & rowCounter - 3).Value = averager / 3
        averager = 0
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
    Next i

End Sub
```